# Getting errors while installing pip package using command prompt

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I am a beginner for using python (3.7.4 version with pip 19.0.3 ), but I have  got an issue with installing pip in python. I tried every way to install pip package after lots of searching on google (I have already set "add python 3.7 to patch", I also checked old stack overflow questions related to this and I tried to install get-pip.py using cmd etc., but I got the same error every time while installing pip using command prompt. ("could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-docx (from version:) No matching distribution found for python-docx". Another problem is pycharm's site-package folder shows in red color.(pycharm version 9.2.1).also there are no modules in site package and cant be imported any well known modules from it.I am using windows 10 home edition.Does anyone have another way to tackle this?

Comment: You forgot to attach the screenshot.

Comment: I am confused, you say you have python3.7 with pip installed, but are unable to install pip? Why would you want to install pip if you already have it?

Comment: Because there is no modules in site-package category and cant be imported any well known modules also when I typed pip --version on cmd it showed "pip 19.0.3".So I thought I should install it first,but i couldnt.What do you think what's happening?

Comment: @Ravi, you are probably doing something wrong while installing the packages. What did you use?

Comment: Also, what screenshot?

Comment: You meant when i installed pip then i used command promt and i typed pip install python.docx but it gave an error like this "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-docx (from version:) No matching distribution found for python-docx".I'm sorry there's no screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the [pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/):

> Programming Languages:
>
> - Python
> - Python :: 2
> - Python :: 2.6
> - Python :: 2.7
> - Python :: 3
> - Python :: 3.3
> - Python :: 3.4

And in the [python-docx documentation](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/install.html):

> Dependencies
>
> Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.3, or 3.4

Your python version (3.7) is not supported by the module you are trying to install.

You should always check these kind of pages for compatibility when you have trouble installing packages

Comment: But I tried to install beautifulsoup and pygame it didn't work.(it gave the same error as mentioned above

Comment: You have mentioned nowhere that other package installations are also not working. Please make a question with a clear problem statement, including the exact error messages you are getting. Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and maybe browse through some other questions with the `pip` tag with similar problem statements to see examples